# Styling the page numbering in LyX

Tags: lyx

I was trying to find a way in order to get the following view of page numbering (on the bottom of the page):

[image]

I tried to read some previous threads but didn't find a way to implement it.

How can I do it in `LyX`?

Comment: How are your footers defined?

Answer (score 2):

A bit hackish, but adding something like

```
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\strut\xrfill[3pt]{0.4pt}\hspace{-1.5pt}( \thepage{} )\hspace{-2,5pt}\xrfill[3pt]{0.4pt}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble in a standard Article-type document will give you

[image]